# Using RSpec2 to test a controller's show action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rspec2

I have a fairly simple Rails 3 project where I've defined a custom route:

```
get 'factions/:name' => 'factions#show', :as => :factions
get 'factions' => 'factions#index'
```

... which when running `rails s` gives me the expected page (`http://localhost:3000/factions/xyz` is HTTP 200 with the `app/views/factions/show.html.haml` being displayed).  However I've tried multiple different ways of expressing a spec that will work, below is my latest incarnation:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FactionsController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'show'" do
    before { get '/xyz' }
    subject { controller }
    it { should respond_with(:success) }
    it { should render_template(:show) }
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

The `GET 'index'` spec passes without complaint but no matter what I do the `GET 'show'` specs cannot pass - even if they do succeed when I am browsing to them locally.

```
1) FactionsController GET 'show' 
     Failure/Error: before { get '/xyz' }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"factions", :action=>"/xyz"}
     # ./spec/controllers/factions_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The action really should be `show` but my `routes.rb` configuration must be incorrect or something.  What gives?

(Additional context: I am using `bundle exec spork` for speeding up my specs and I have restarted the `spork` server multiple times just to make sure I'm not completely insane.)

Comment: Also try `rake routes` to make sure the route exists as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
before { get '/xyz' }
```

To:

```
before { get :show, :name => 'xyz' }
```